# Custom Calendar Type for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, locale, globalization

I want to have Persian calendar in windows.
I mean every date in windows be in the Persian Calendar; date of creation of files, dates used in ms office software, etc.

Is it possible?
Where should i start?

I know programming in c++/c, c#, java and python languages.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just pick the "Persian" format option in the Region and Language bit of Control Panel?

Comment: Changing the format only transliterate the Month names in Persian. number of days in each month is different for Persian calendar.

Comment: I see.  Microsoft offer this tool for creating / modifying locales, so it might do what you need:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5662

Comment: Thanks for reply, it seams to work on Windows Vista only. I can not install it on my windows 8 or 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at this time.